# How to Flex items vertically in Elementor Woocommerce Products

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

after hours of failing in CSS code to find a solution i am reachingg out for help! 
A common issue i find with woocommerce (wordpress, elementor)
is with the widget “products” which is an Elementor widget.

Some of my products have more than 1 line of title, causing the items in other container and the same line look bad (not flexing all over the container vertically)

Well i assume its not a great explanation so i added

i just want the button that says “Buy now” (not in english :D) to stick to the bottom of the column.

Thanks, Ben

Comment: send us a link to your shop

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the uneven buttons is the difference in height of the item titles. A simple solution is to add custom css in your themes customizer or in elementor to force a min height of the title to ensure its always the same height.

Adding this to your custom css will fix the alignment for you

```
.woocommerce-loop-product__title{
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

You can experiment with the height to find the ideal one. 100px is just a quick recommendation that appeared to be working well.

See attached image for example.

[image]

Comment: I managed to solve it in a diffrent way however your way is also nice. Tnx :)